# Clang format not always respecting BinPackParameters: false

Tags: c++, clang-format

I'm trying to use a .clang-format file with Visual Studio 2017 but it doesn't always seem to respect the BinPackParameters argument which I set to false.

With the following parameters set:

```
AlignAfterOpenBracket: AlwaysBreak
AllowAllParametersOfDeclarationOnNextLine: false
BinPackArguments: false
BinPackParameters: false
ColumnLimit: 110
```

I would expect my method calls that were too long (i.e. greater than the ColumnWidth parameter) to always line break every parameter to a method so that they are each on different lines like so:

```
LongMethodNameCall(
    someLongParameter1,
    someLongParameter2,
    someLongParameter3,
    someLongParameter4 );
```

This is the case sometimes, but other times I get:

```
LongMethodNameCall(
    someLongParameter1, someLongParameter2, someLongParameter3, someLongParameter4 );
```

To be clear I want it to **always line-break after the opening bracket and put each parameter onto one line if the whole statement exceeds the ColumnWidth parameter**.

Here is my .clang-format file:

```
Language: Cpp
#DisableFormat: true

AccessModifierOffset: -4
AlignAfterOpenBracket: AlwaysBreak
AlignConsecutiveAssignments: false
AlignConsecutiveDeclarations: false
AlignEscapedNewlines: Left
AlignOperands: true
AlignTrailingComments: false
AllowAllParametersOfDeclarationOnNextLine: false
AllowShortBlocksOnASingleLine: false
AllowShortCaseLabelsOnASingleLine: false
AllowShortFunctionsOnASingleLine: Inline
AllowShortIfStatementsOnASingleLine: false
AllowShortLoopsOnASingleLine: false
AlwaysBreakAfterDefinitionReturnType: None
AlwaysBreakAfterReturnType: None
AlwaysBreakBeforeMultilineStrings: false
AlwaysBreakTemplateDeclarations: true
BinPackArguments: false
BinPackParameters: false
BraceWrapping:
    AfterClass:      true   
    AfterControlStatement: true
    AfterEnum:       true
    AfterFunction:   true          
    AfterNamespace:  false                
    AfterStruct:     true
    AfterUnion:      true
    BeforeCatch:     true
    BeforeElse:      true   
    IndentBraces:    false
BreakBeforeBinaryOperators: None
BreakBeforeBraces: Custom
BreakBeforeInheritanceComma: false
BreakBeforeTernaryOperators: false
BreakConstructorInitializers: AfterColon
BreakStringLiterals: true
ColumnLimit: 110
CompactNamespaces: false
ConstructorInitializerAllOnOneLineOrOnePerLine: false
ConstructorInitializerIndentWidth: 4
ContinuationIndentWidth: 4
Cpp11BracedListStyle: false
ExperimentalAutoDetectBinPacking: false
FixNamespaceComments: true
IncludeCategories:
    - Regex:           '\/stdafx.h'
      Priority:        -1
IndentCaseLabels: true
IndentWidth: 4
IndentWrappedFunctionNames: false
KeepEmptyLinesAtTheStartOfBlocks: false
MaxEmptyLinesToKeep: 1
NamespaceIndentation: None
PenaltyBreakAssignment: 100
PenaltyBreakBeforeFirstCallParameter: 0
PenaltyBreakComment: 0
PenaltyBreakFirstLessLess: 100
PenaltyBreakString: 50
PenaltyExcessCharacter: 20
PenaltyReturnTypeOnItsOwnLine: 1000
PointerAlignment: Left
ReflowComments: true
SortIncludes: true
SortUsingDeclarations: true
SpaceAfterCStyleCast: false
SpaceAfterTemplateKeyword: false
SpaceBeforeAssignmentOperators: true
SpaceBeforeParens: ControlStatements
SpaceInEmptyParentheses: false
SpacesInAngles: true
SpacesInCStyleCastParentheses: false
SpacesInContainerLiterals: true
SpacesInParentheses: true
SpacesInSquareBrackets: true
TabWidth: 4
UseTab: Never
```

Answer (score 0):

To clarify, it is crucial to set `PenaltyReturnTypeOnItsOwnLine: 1000`, which you are already doing. It prevents having the return code on a single line if it enables fitting the rest on a single line:

```
std::vector<std::string> 
    test(std::string const & var1, std::string const & var2);
```

becomes

```
std::vector<std::string> test(std::string const & var1, 
                              std::string const & var2);
```

Answer (score -1):

The only time BinPackParameters: false is not respected is when **AllowAllParametersOfDeclarationOnNextLine** is set to **true**, which is not in your case.

I tried with the provided config and could not reproduce the issue.

The tool has probably been modified in the meanwhile.